# Yii zii.widgets.grid.CGridView viewButtonUrl problems

Tags: php, yii

```
$rid = ""
if( isset( $_GET['rid'] ) {
    $rid = $_GET['rid'];
}

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'guests-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'name',
        'address',
        'contact_numbers',
        'email_addresses',
        /*
        'company_name',
        'company_contact_nos',
        'person_to_notify_emergency',
        'person_to_notify_contact_no',
        */
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'viewButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("guests/view",array("id"=>$data->idGuests,"rid"=>"$rid"))',

        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

I'm sure the $rid exist because this is my url

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php?r=guests/admin&rid=1
```

**Here's the error:**
[image]

The error is caused by the viewButtonUrl, I know that the reason why $_GET['rid'] has an error because all variables in a CGridView should b in the $model variable.

Is there a way to fix this one? Your help will be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks!

Comment: It won't solve your problem but you're checking for `isset($_GET['id'])` instead of `rid`.

Comment: Are both code snippets inside your view? Or is the `$rid` assignment in your controller and the rest in your view?

Comment: @DanielM:That's just a typo :) I'll edit it

Comment: @DanielM: Those are all in my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using single quotes and thus giving the variable to the CGridView component.

CGridView then tries to parse the string. However, in CGridView's context, there isn't a variable `$rid`.

Use double quotes in this case and escape the double quotes inside the string.

```
'Yii::app()->createUrl("guests/view",array("id"=>$data->idGuests,"rid"=>"$rid"))'
```

Becomes

```
"Yii::app()->createUrl(\"guests/view\",array(\"id\"=>\$data->idGuests,\"rid\"=>\"$rid\"))"
```